# Value of global variable that gets its value inside of socket.on is not accessible outside of it

Tags: javascript, sockets

```
var snake;

p.setup = function () {
  canvas = p.createCanvas(600, 600)
  socket = io.connect('http://localhost:1337')

socket.on('activate-device-controls', function(_isPhone){
    if(_isPhone) {
      isPhone = _isPhone;
      snake = new Snake(null, null, p, snakeImg)
      food = new Food(p)

      const snakeData = {
        x: snake.x,
        y: snake.y,
        color: snake.color,
        points: snake.points,
        tail: snake.tail
      }

      const foodData = {
        x: food.vec.x,
        y: food.vec.y
      }
      // Handle server disconnection
      socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        socket.close()
      })

      // send the snake info to the server
      socket.emit('start', {snakeData, foodData})

      socket.on('serverUpdate', function (data) {
        snakes = data.snakes
        foods = data.foods
      })

        p.frameRate(10)
     }
  })
};
```

We cannot figure out why snake remains undefined outside of the callback function in socket.on(..). However, I can see that snake is being reassigned with new Snake(), it just doesn't exist anywhere else. We cannot figure out why. Please help

Comment: Since a lot of code is clearly omitted, might you have a variable named `snake` defined elsewhere in the scope accessible to the `socket.on` callback which is shading the access to the global var of the same name? Also, is there any chance that `new Snake()` is returning undefined?

Comment: new Snake() does return a value within the callback. And there are no other references we see. I will add more code too.